# Measure Distance from iPhone Camera to an object using camera

Tags: iphone, xcode

I would like to implement an app which measures the distance between the camera and the focused object . Kindly help me to start this application . Even I don't know how to start this app . Please give me some ideas .

Comment: hi sri have you got an idea for this?

Comment: @sri Hello, have you find anything related to this? cause i have to develop same feature. thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its very difficult! Iphone has many features, to implement this you either need a tracking beam or something like a laser. You can try using GPS and get the distance but focusing on a object definitely need some pre loaded data. I would suggest a method called "Parallax method", its difficult this method is used by astronomers to measure the distance between earth and stars. Its definitely possible but requires lot research and development, Iphone  camera has limitation ,some R&D is required before u use parallax method because it requires camera to capture the photo at different angles. And lots of mathematical stuff (like trigonometry) definitely possible

Comment: Thanks a lot rishi I got some boost up .

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple approach, anyway, it's not that acourate. You need to take the height of the person using your app or, to be more specific, the height (y position in real space) of the lens. By using triangle formulas you can measure the distance.

Imagine a triangle where `A` is the foot of the user, `B` the iPhone camera und `C` the bottom of the object you want to know the distance to. You've got `c`, the height of the person (or the height of the camera lens), angle `α`, which is 90° and angle `β` which you can get from the iPhone by the accelerometer. The rest is math:

```
γ = 180 - α - β
b = c * sin(β) / sin(γ)
```

But there are some limitations: The object you want to measure the distance to and the user must be on the same level or at least the user must know to measure to a point at foot level. From about 10 meters this method gets really inaccurate. And: You must normalize the accelerometer by substracting the offset – for example by let the user lay it down plain in a horizontal surface.

[image]

Hope this helps.

(And sorry for my poor mathematical english ;))

Answer (score 2):

Although in theory you could get this working, I don't think this can practically be done with an iPhone camera.
The advantage is, that the iPhone camera has a fixed focal distance, so if you know the size of the object you want to measure, you can calculate the distance to it. If you don't know the size, you would need to make several pictures or a video from different angles. But then you would need to know the distance or the location of each frame. You could use GPS for that, but it's not accurate enough unless we are talking about objects that are several hundreds of meters away. If that's the case, your would need different images of the object from positions that are also far away from each other to get a decent accuracy. 
Over all it's possible in theory, but I doubt you get any kind of satisfying results.

Comment: You are right jimpic I didn't get any satisfying results but added some idea by reading your answer +1 for your answer.